# Startup form not showing in Access 2013 runtime

Tags: vba, runtime, ms-access-2010

I'm writing a front end application in MS Access 2010 saved as a standard accdb which users will only be able to use Access runtime to open. Our IT department has kindly installed the 2013 runtime rather than the 2010 runtime on a test machine for me to check my development on.

I'm having some issues getting anything to show in Runtime on this machine, yet when I use the /runtime switch in a shortcut on MY machine, everything works as expected. What is happening on the test machine is a dialogue warning of "A potential security concern has been identified" comes up with OK and Cancel. If I click on OK, the database opens as far as I can tell, and code that's in the form_open event of the startup form runs (checks to see the location of the file isn't a network drive to ensure that users copy the front end to their desktop) and a version control query to match the client with the latest version of backend. However the form never appears, and I get no errors/crashes or other unexpected events.

What could I have done wrong, or is it connected with the security warning? My gut says that's a red herring as the location check and version checking code does run, ie if I run it from the network drive then it gives the msgbox it was meant to.

Many thanks, this is my first time using runtime.

Comment: I have added msgbox commands through the form_open sub and they all open, suggesting that the code is processing correctly. The only thing that isn't working is that the form itself does not show. Please, someone. Put me out of my misery. What have I done wrong!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After several days of searching, I've finally solved the problem.

I had been developing on a laptop with a second screen connected. For some inane reason, Access remembered this, and decided to display the form on the second screen. Unfortunately, my users don't have a 2nd screen.......

Selecting Auto Center=Yes in the form properties solved the problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you.  This just solved a similar problem I have been struggling with

Comment: Just wanted to add a thanks 5 years down the line - this answered the EXACT same issue I had with an Access form not popping in runtime after the security popup on other machines but mine. It too was the `AutoCenter` property being set to `False`.